# can't get Container's value in Zend2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-session

Actually I am storing on value in the container in index action then i am fetching that value in same action but i am not able to fetch that value in another action of that same controller as well as in another controller...am I missing Something?

This is my code..

- IndexController

  ```
  class IndexController extends AbstractActionController  {

  public function indexAction() {

      $session=new Container('temp');
      $session->username="bhavik";

      error_log("in index Controller value=$session->username");
      return new ViewModel();
    }
  public function welcomeAction() {

       $session = new Container('temp');
       error_log("in index controller welcome action value==".$session->username);
       $username = $session->username;
       return new ViewModel();
    }
  }
  ```

this is the configuration in

- module.php

  ```
  public function initSession($config)
   {
  $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
  $sessionConfig->setOptions($config);
  $sessionManager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
  $sessionManager->start();
  Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
  }

       public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
  $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
  $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
  $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
  $this->initSession(array(
  //            'remember_me_seconds' => 240,
      'use_cookies' => true,
      'cookie_lifetime' => 2592000,
  //            'cookie_httponly' => true,
      'gc_maxlifetime' => 2592000
  ));
  }
  ```

this is it and all common configs and use..
I am able fetch the value of $session->username in index action but not in the welcome action..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to `print_r($_SESSION)` in `indexAction` after `$session->username="bhavik"` line. Do you have `username` key here?

Comment: yeah it is there see this Array ( [__ZF] => Array ( [_REQUEST_ACCESS_TIME] => 1427087263.14 ) [temp] => Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject Object ( [storage:protected] => Array ( [username] => bhavik ) [flag:protected] => 2 [iteratorClass:protected] => ArrayIterator [protectedProperties:protected] => Array ( [0] => storage [1] => flag [2] => iteratorClass [3] => protectedProperties ) ) )

Comment: Do you have PHPSESSID cookie? Is it persists between queries? Looks like your code is OK, but some problems with environment.

Comment: I have installed the zend framework again  now its working..

Comment: and yeah I do have that cookies..but i think it might be destroying the session after calling the controller ..don't know what was the problem there?